# HTTPS for only one ASP.NET page (Login.aspx), HTTP always for rest of site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ssl

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 webforms site with an SSL certificate on it.  I can currently go to the site via HTTP or HTTPS and it works fine.  Regardless or the merits of the decision, what my manager wants is to be able to go to http://example.com/Login.aspx and have that redirect to https://example.com/Login.aspx so that HTTPS is enforced on ONLY this Login.aspx page.  However, when logged in (Login.aspx redirects user to Default.aspx), the rest of the site needs to *always* be regular HTTP.

Bottom line: Login.aspx should always be HTTPS, regardless if the user entered in HTTP or HTTPS when going to the site.  The rest of the site should always be HTTP.  How can I achieve this via IIS or a code solution?

UPDATE 1: Here's the coded solution I've got working.  I'd like to try with IIS Rewrite Module, just waiting on IT support to install it for me. RequireHttpsOnLogin() is called in Global.asax.cs in method Application_BeginRequest:

```
public void RequireHttpsOnLogin()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath.EndsWith("Login.aspx"))
        {
            //On HTTP login page on server, redirect to HTTPS
            Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }
        else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(true) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false) && !HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath.EndsWith("Login.aspx"))
        {
            //Not on HTTP login page and on server, redirect to HTTP
            Response.Redirect("http://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 2: The following is working for the Login page to be HTTPS, but not the other pages to be HTTP always.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(Login.aspx)" ignoreCase="true"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{R:1}" pattern="(login.aspx)" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding below in your Web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(Login.aspx)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Looks like I need the URL Rewrite Module on my IIS to make this work.  I'll give that a try and see what I need to do to make your answer work.

Comment: if you can't install this module, alternatively you can redirect in code; in your Master Page --> Page_Load, detect URL has Login.aspx and redirect to https; var xredir = string.Format("https://{0}{1}{2}", Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"], Request.ServerVariables["SCRIPT_NAME"], (xqstr.Equals(string.Empty) ? string.Empty : string.Format("?{0}", xqstr)));
                    Response.Redirect(xredir);

Comment: This works when I went to the login page with just http it redirected it to https.  But once logged in, all the other pages remained https.  How can I make these rules so the Login page is always HTTPS and the other pages are always HTTP?

Comment: Copy paste the same rule, add negate="true" in match tag; change input and action type from HTTPS to HTTP

Comment: @user2169261...see my UPDATE 2 in the original post for what I did.  It still works for the Login page and forces HTTPS, but when the Login page redirects to the home page or other pages, those pages still remain HTTPS.  I need those non-Login pages to be HTTP always.  Maybe I'm missing something else?

Comment: Actually, my UPDATE 2 in the original post is what I did to make this work. :)  Slightly different and not sure exactly how it works, but it does.

Comment: The only issue I see with this now is that the linked files (css, JS, images) are all http and creating a mixed-content scenario so that the browsers don't show a padlock symbol for the page.  I'm not sure how to get these content files to be https only on this one Login.aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

You could put code in Global.asax.cs in method Application_BeginRequest to force  the redirection as needed.

Comment: Thanks @codenoire.  Any idea on what the code would be to do this for the Login.aspx only?  The logic should be:  If HTTP and on Login page, redirect to HTTPS.  If on any other page of the site, always be HTTP.